# How can I do to enable the registry actions in the WSO2 ESB?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have a problem with the ESB 4.8.1. I have 2 environments and I use the same user and role to login into the ESB, but I have seen that in one environment I haven't got available the actions (add delete move and copy a resource) in the registry.

With buttons:

[image]

Without buttons:

[image]

I am looking for internet and in the wso2 official documentation but I had found nothing.

Where do I need to change in order to enable this buttons?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the file registry.xml (wso2esb-4.8.1/repository/conf/) because I had the tag readOnly with the value true.

I had:

```
<readOnly>true</readOnly>
```

I put:

```
<readOnly>false</readOnly>
```